# How can I increment the value of an input array?

Tags: jquery

I have an area on my website that I allow users to update their profile information.

**html**

```
<div class="my-class">
    <input type="text" name="fields[myFieldHandle][1][fields][firstName]" value="">
    <button type="button" id="add">Add Another</button>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#add').click(function (event) {
    $('.my-class').clone().insertAfter('div.my-class');
});
```

All is well, I am able to clone the text input. However, I need to be able to increment the `[1]` value by one. I could try matching the string, but I feel that is assuming quite a bit. Is there a more effective way to clone this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[myFieldHandle][1][fields][firstName]" value="">
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[myFieldHandle][2][fields][firstName]" value="">
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gje8qfpe/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cloning the *first* `div`, clone the last one so you'll get the last `input`.

You can then increment its number as follows:

```
$('#add').click(function (event) {
  $('.my-class:last')
    .clone()
    .insertAfter('div.my-class:last')
    .find('input')                                       //get the input
    .attr('name', function(_, currentValue) {            //get its current value
      return currentValue.replace(/\d/, function(num) {  //replace the numeric part
        return +num + 1;                                 //with its value + 1
      });
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6tL8sync/1)